# Disable td in bootstrap angularjs depend on role permission

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to `Bootstrap` and `AngularJS`, trying to provide permission depends on the user credential I am trying to hide a row(`<td>`) in a table.

`abc.html`

```
<td><span type="submit" data-ng-hide="edit" data-ng-click="edit = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" disabled="disabled"></span>
        <span type="submit" data-ng-show="edit" data-ng-click="edit = false; save()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        <span type="submit" data-ng-show="edit" data-ng-click="edit = false; cancel()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
```

I am not sure about the js in the  factory controller can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Set the attribute of the `tr` as `ng-show=isVisible` and in your controller set the value of it as `true` or `false` based on authorization result.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML would go like this

```
<table ng-repeat="user in users">
 <tr ng-hide="user.isAuthorized">
  <td>Hey!! I am authorized </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And in your controller, Idk how you get the user details (prob from an api), but then you would have something like this

```
$scope.users = [{'name': 'John', 'isAuthorized': true},
 {'name': 'Doe', 'isAuthorized': false}];
```